# Google Sheet query to select one column and do two count

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to select column A, count column A and column B and group by A. But when I do that, count B return the same count as A.

Here is a sheet with an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zpI3YjLYh9Mv2KCeuNk5TWtNKfyXpMb6OpGFlQtZ3Os/edit?usp=sharing

What I am aiming for here is for count(B) to be based on column B and not column A like it is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following formulas:

for `City totals`

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({A2:A;B2:B}))
```

for `Pick up`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E<>"",COUNTIF(A:A,E2:E),""))
```

for `Drop off`

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E<>"",COUNTIF(B:B,E2:E),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @basic, what is in the column H2:H though?

Comment: ups, I deleted some experiments and the column indexes changed. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
=query({query(A2:B, "SELECT A, COUNT(A) WHERE A is not null GROUP BY A label A 'City Totals', COUNT(A) 'Pick Up' "),
query(A2:B, "SELECT B, COUNT(B) WHERE B is not null GROUP BY B label B 'City Totals', COUNT(B) 'Drop Off' ")},
"Select Col1,Col2,Col4")
```

[image: example]

---

**Multiple formulas:**

**D2**: `=query(unique(flatten(A2:B)),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not NULL")`

**E2**: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D15,query(A2:A, "SELECT A, COUNT(A) WHERE A is not null GROUP BY A label A 'City Totals', COUNT(A) 'Pick Up' "),{2},FALSE),0))`

**F2**: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D15,query(B2:B, "SELECT B, COUNT(B) WHERE B is not null GROUP BY B label B 'City Totals', COUNT(B) 'Drop Off' "),{2},FALSE),0))`

[image: example2]

Comment: Thanks Marios, that is almost it, the issue with this approach is that it only seems to work for 3 cities? When I added more cities I got a reference error.

Comment: because column A and B need to have the same cities. If you add city 4 in column A then you need to add city 4 in column B. @Windbox

Comment: I see, is that the only way of doing it? Because sometimes I may have a delivery or pickup in a city that doesn't exist on column A or B.

Comment: @Windbox I don't believe there is other solution in one formula at least.

Comment: @Windbox If you want, check out my multiple formula solution :)